# Making div scroll from within Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to react, I would like a div to scroll up as it starts to overflow, and I am trying to do it the proper way with react, but can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following in my render method:

```
render:function(){

    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="title">talkin folk</div>
        <div className="chatBox">
          <div className="chatRooms">
            <p className="large">rooms</p>
            {this.arrayOfRooms}
          </ div>
          <div className="typingBox">
            <div ref='dialog' key='dialog' className="dialog"> // div to scroll
              {this.arrayOfMsgToRender}
            </div>
            <div className="userType">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="You:"
                label="email"
                value={this.state.msg}
                onChange={this.handleInput}
              />
            <input id="doneButton" type="submit" value="send" onClick={this.handleSend} />
            </div>
          </ div>
        </ div>
      </ div>
    );
  }
```

In the above code, it is the div dialog, that I would like to have scroll up automatically as it starts to overflow.

I tried to do something like:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
  var node = this.getDOMNode('dialog');
  node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
},
```

But that wont work

Comment: have you tried this.refs.dialog? since 'dialog' is a div and not a react custom element, you don't need to use this.getDOMNode. [this](http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/) article might help.

Comment: hi fzxt, you where right this.refs.dialog worked, could you use that as an answer below, and I will accept it. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Sure thing. I'll write an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access a DOM node within a react component, you can do something like this:

say you have a `<div ref = "hello">Hello World.</div>`

You can access this DOM node in react  via: `this.refs.hello`.

The only thing you have to watch out for is this ONLY works for HTML elements, not React elements. For React elements, you need to use `this.getDOMNode(this)`, and work through it.